# Setting cookie in Cypress give error: "cy.setCookie() had an unexpected error setting the requested cookie in Chrome. Error: Sanitizing cookie failed"

Tags: cypress

### TL;DR

What is it actually that Cypress gets sad about, when it throws this error:

```txt
! CypressError

cy.setCookie() had an unexpected error setting the requested cookie in Chrome.

> Error: Sanitizing cookie failed
```

?

---

### Detailed description

I have a function that sets a bunch of cookies, from a `.txt`-file. This is so I can 'log in' by executing this function and setting all necessary cookies.

But when I do it, Cypress throws an error that I don't understand (see the error in the TL;DR-section above).

**Stack trace:**

```
 at <unknown> (http://mylocaltestdomain.test/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:139868:76)
From previous event:
    at <unknown> (http://mylocaltestdomain.test/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:140071:17)
    at <unknown> (http://mylocaltestdomain.test/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:152530:14)
From previous event:
    at $Cy.retryIfCommandAUTOriginMismatch (http://mylocaltestdomain.test/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:152529:25)
    at Context.setCookie (http://mylocaltestdomain.test/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:140068:17)
    at wrapped (http://mylocaltestdomain.test/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157849:43)
From Your Spec Code:
    at Context.eval (webpack:///./cypress/e2e/preparations/prep-wp-login-and-cookies.cy.js:40:6)
    
From Node.js Internals:
  Error: Sanitizing cookie failed
      at <unknown> (<embedded>:708:509041)
      at _._handleMessage (<embedded>:708:511054)
      at A.<anonymous> (<embedded>:708:510873)
      at A.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at g.B (<embedded>:708:496211)
      at g.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at g.dataMessage (<embedded>:708:476631)
      at <unknown> (<embedded>:708:476164)
      at <unknown> (<embedded>:708:467511)
      at <unknown> (<embedded>:708:468452)
      at afterWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:497:5)
```

**My code**

```javascript
Cypress.Commands.add( "setWordPressAuthCookies", () => {

  let authCookiesPath = 'development/tmp/authCookies.txt';
  cy.fixture( authCookiesPath, 'utf8' )
  .then( (cookies) => {
    cookies.forEach( (cookie) => {
      // cy.log( JSON.stringify( cookie ) ); // See the cookie contents
      
      cy.setCookie( cookie.name, cookie.value, {
        domain: Cypress.env('currentDomain'),
        path: cookie.path,
        secure: cookie.secure,
        httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly,
        expiry: cookie.expiry
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Contents of the cookie the it shows the error with:

```json
{
  "name": "wp-settings-12",
  "value": "editor%3Dhtml%26ampampampnetwork_users_list_mode%3Dlist%26ampampamplibraryContent%3Dbrowse%26ampamplibraryContent%3Dbrowse%26ampamphidetb%3D0%26ampampmfold%3Do%26ampampimgsize%3Dfull%26ampampalign%3Dleft%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26advImgDetails%3Dshow",
  "path": "/",
  "secure": false,
  "httpOnly": false,
  "expiry": 1703771330.714386,
  "domain": "mylocaltestdomain.text"
}
```

**All cookies**

Here are all the cookies that this function should set:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "wp-settings-12",
    "value": "editor%3Dhtml%26ampampampnetwork_users_list_mode%3Dlist%26ampampamplibraryContent%3Dbrowse%26ampamplibraryContent%3Dbrowse%26ampamphidetb%3D0%26ampampmfold%3Do%26ampampimgsize%3Dfull%26ampampalign%3Dleft%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26advImgDetails%3Dshow",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "expiry": 1703771330.714386,
    "domain": "mylocaltestdomain.test"
  },
  {
    "name": "wp-settings-time-12",
    "value": "1672235330",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "expiry": 1703771330.714419,
    "domain": "mylocaltestdomain.test"
  },
  {
    "name": "wordpress_80f89aaabbb62cf5ead75a68566e5b74",
    "value": "my_wordpress_username%7C1672408128%7CrnwumENI8t74dgQmv0tsY98tDRqGdxSR09t2BA61Lt3%7C744e72790320da01c1e359610e45b697272223cf3031a84cf9728e26d88e5af8",
    "path": "/wp-content/plugins",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "domain": "mylocaltestdomain.test"
  },
  {
    "name": "wordpress_test_cookie",
    "value": "WP%20Cookie%20check",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "domain": "mylocaltestdomain.test"
  },
  {
    "name": "wordpress_80f89aaabbb62cf5ead75a68566e5b74",
    "value": "my_wordpress_username%7C1672408128%7CrnwumENI8t74dgQmv0tsY98tDRqGdxSR09t2BA61Lt3%7C744e72790320da01c1e359610e45b697272223cf3031a84cf9728e26d88e5af8",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "domain": "mylocaltestdomain.test"
  },
  {
    "name": "wordpress_logged_in_80f89aaabbb62cf5ead75a68566e5b74",
    "value": "my_wordpress_username%7C1672408128%7CrnwumENI8t74dgQmv0tsY98tDRqGdxSR09t2BA61Lt3%7C11d4ba33c9b1116655e41449a92f98811579707cfec296866bed8619fdbfeb8a",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "domain": "mylocaltestdomain.test"
  }
]
```

I have this working on a couple of different sites. This is however, the first time I try to do this on a multisite.

What is it actually that Cypress gets sad about here?

---

### Initial solution attempts

I tried the obvious first:

- Restart Cypress
- Regenerate the `authCookies.txt`-file and trying again.

No change.

### Solution attempt 1: Read the documentation-link

The error points to this URL: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/setcookie. But I can't find anything about this error in there. Not sanitizing it or anything.

I also tried generating the authCookies.txt-file again (that's another function that does that). But I get the same result.

### Solution attempt 2: Skip the (troublesome) cookie

I tried changing the 'setting' of the cookies to skip the one listed here, like this:

```javascript
Cypress.Commands.add( "setWordPressAuthCookies", () => {

  let authCookiesPath = 'development/tmp/authCookies.txt';
  cy.fixture( authCookiesPath, 'utf8' )
  .then( (cookies) => {
    cookies.forEach( (cookie) => {
      // cy.log( JSON.stringify( cookie ) ); // See the cookie contents
      
      if( ! ['wp-settings-12'].includes(cookie.name) ){  // <-- MY ATTEMPTED FIX START
        cy.setCookie( cookie.name, cookie.value, {
          domain: Cypress.env('currentDomain'),
          path: cookie.path,
          secure: cookie.secure,
          httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly,
          expiry: cookie.expiry
        });
      }                                                  // <-- MY ATTEMPTED FIX END
    });
  });
});
```

It just throws the same error for the next one (by the name: `wp-settings-time-12`).
And if I skip that, then it `wordpress_80f89aaabbb62cf5ead75a68566e5b74`.

### Solution attempt 3: Set the cookies via JavaScript (and not Cypress)

This seems like quite the excessive operation, [rewriting the function to do this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).
And I would like to trust Cypress - and not just find weird shortcuts.

### Solution attempt 4: Update Cypress

I was on Cypress version `11.2.0`.
I updated to `12.2.0`.

Same result.

### Solution attempt 5: Different browser

I tired in Firefox Developer Edition and got a slightly different error:

```
setCookie   wordpress_test_cookie, WP%20Cookie%20check, {domain: mylocaltestdomain.test/subsite-path}

CypressError
cy.setCookie() had an unexpected error setting the requested cookie in Firefox Developer Edition.

> Error: Permission denied to set cookie {"domain":"mylocaltestdomain.test/subsite-path","expirationDate":2303459061,"firstPartyDomain":null,"httpOnly":false,"name":"wordpress_test_cookie","partitionKey":null,"path":"/","sameSite":"no_restriction","secure":false,"storeId":null,"url":"http://mylocaltestdomain.test/subsite-path/","value":"WP%20Cookie%20check"}
```

Maybe it has something to do with the `subsite-path`. Hmm...!

Comment: `Cookies.preserveOnce` and `Cookies.defaults` were deprecated in Cypress `9.7.0` and have been replaced with `cy.session`, which you can eliminate the above problems -

Answer (score 1):

The culprit for me was a new line at the end of my fixture file. Those are often auto-added by IDEs on save due to user configuration or `.editorconfig` rules.